# Functional use of Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Another model for a growth function for a limited pupulation is given by the Gompertz function, which is a solution of the differential equation

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t} =c\ln\left(\frac{k}{p}\right)p $$
where $c$ is a constant and K is the carrying capacity.

Solve this differential equation for $c=0.25 = \frac{1}{4}$, $K=4000$, and initial population $P_0=600$.

This what I've gotten so far.

$$\frac{1}{c\ln(\frac Kp)p}dP=dt $$

$$ \int  \frac{4}{\ln(\frac{4000}{p})p}dp=\int 1 dt $$

$$ P(t) = 4000e^{e^{-\frac{c-t}{4}}} $$ 
I'm confused by the $e^e$ part. How is this possible?

trying to solve for c I get

$$ .15=e^{e^{-\frac{c}{4}}} $$

$$ ln|.15| = e^{-\frac{c}{4}} $$

$$ ln|ln|.15|| = -c/4 $$

Comment: What did you exactly meant by the on to the last line? What is *inte*?

Comment: Integral. I'm not sure how to program it into the program as it keeps messing up when I try.

Comment: Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: You have your signs wrong in a couple of places. Also, your liberal usage of uppercase and lowercase notation makes the story not so easy to follow.